# bash array + how to set variable in bash array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, awk

we set the "list" variable with sdb - sdz range

```
# MAX=z
# list=$(eval echo sd{b..$MAX})
# echo $list
sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg sdh sdi sdj sdk sdl sdm sdn sdo sdp sdq sdr sds sdt sdu sdv sdw sdx sdy sdz
```

until now its ok

now we set the $list in array as the follwing

```
#array=( echo $list )
```

but when we print the first value of the array we get "echo"

```
#echo ${array[0]}
echo
```

what is wrong here?

expected results:

```
#echo ${array[0]}
sdb


#echo ${array[1]}
sdc

#echo ${array[2]}
sdc
```

or

```
# echo  "${list[counter++]}"
```

Comment: `array=( echo $list )` populates `array` with `echo` then the contents of `$list` after word splitting, file name, expansion, etc. Google how to use arrays, shell quoting rules, `$( foo )` vs `( foo )`, etc.

Comment: Either do `array=($list)`,  `array=( $(echo $list))` but the latter is not best practice.  (Neither is, really!) Just assign the array directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ max=z
$ list=( $(eval echo sd{b..$max}) )
$ echo "${list[*]}"
sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg sdh sdi sdj sdk sdl sdm sdn sdo sdp sdq sdr sds sdt sdu sdv sdw sdx sdy sdz
$ echo "${list[1]}"
sdc
```